# Gradle не собирает проект

Tags: java, android, generics

*Gradle* в `Android Studio` не собирает проект, ругается на ошибку в коде, где стоит аннотация `Suppress Warnings`. Что делать?

Код:

```
   public LinkedList<Item> items;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void restoreFromBundle( Bundle bundle ) {
        pos = bundle.getInt( POS );
        type = Type.valueOf( bundle.getString( TYPE ) );
        items = new LinkedList<>((Collection<? extends Item>) bundle.getCollection(ITEMS));
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
 Error:(373, 81) error: incompatible types: Collection<Bundlable>
  cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У нас есть примерно такие классы:

```
interface Bundlable {}

class Item implements Bundlable {}

class Bundle {
    public Collection<Bundlable> getCollection( String key ) {
        return null; //something...
    }
}
```

Обобщенные типы в java инвариантны, т.е. `Collection<Item>` не является наследником `Collection<Bundlable>`, несмотря на то, что `Item` реализует `Bundlable`. Поэтому `javac`, который используется Android Studio, не дает выполнить приведение

```
new LinkedList<>( (Collection<? extends Item>)bundle.getCollection( "items" ) );
```

т.к. с его точки зрения `Collection<? extends Item>` никак не может наследовать `Collection<Bundlable>`.

Оригинальный код писался, видимо, в Eclipse, который так делать позволяет.

Что с этим делать? Если можно править код `Bundle`, то лучше заменить возвращаемый тип:

```
public Collection<? extends Bundlable> getCollection( String key )
```

Форма `<? extends Bundlable>` означает ковариантность, т.е. наследниками будут все коллекции классов, расширяющих `Bundlable`, включая `Collection<Item>`. Останется предупреждение про "unchecked cast", поскольку у нас java, type erasure и во время выполнения нельзя проверить, что возвращается действительно коллекция `Item`.

Если править `Bundle` нельзя, то можно сделать приведение к `Object`, чтобы компилятор от вас отвязался:

```
(Collection<? extends Item>)(Object)bundle.getCollection( "items" )
```

или перекидать объекты вручную, как это в некоторых местах [делается](https://github.com/watabou/pixel-dungeon/blob/ca458a28f053612973d5d6059dae5f6f2ca4fcb7/src/com/watabou/pixeldungeon/levels/Level.java#L258):

```
List<Item> items = new LinkedList<Item>();
for ( Bundlable b : bundle.getCollection( "items" ) ) ) {
    items.add( (Item)b );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас несовпадение типа данных в коллекции `items`, объявленной как `Collection<Bundlable>` и типа который вы пытаетесь в неё положить - `Collection<? extends Item>`. Вам надо сделать так, чтобы типы данных в коллекции совпадали с типом назначаемых в неё элементов.

Comment: Я немного подправил. И этот код не мой, все должно работать.

Comment: @Дмитрий, попробуйте вооббще убрать кастование, т.е. `(Collection<? extends Item>)`